# Problem with context update and display in a function

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

everyone, I am having trouble recovering a **React hook context**.

On my connection page, I make a call to my database/login my username and password are well recognized I get the Token in response which I put in my hooks and in an array.

When submitting the form my state users change well but I think it takes a little time and suddenly when I want to continue in my function with an if ... the table is empty

```
export default function SignIn() {
  const { addUser, error, isLoged, users } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const classes = useStyles();
  let emailInput;
  let passwordInput;
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newUser = {
      email: emailInput,
      password: passwordInput
    };
    console.log(newUser);
    addUser(newUser);
    console.log(users);
  };
  const handleChangeMail = e => {
    emailInput = e.target.value;
  };
  const handleChangePass = e => {
    passwordInput = e.target.value;
  };
}
```

I even manage to display in the render my users

[image: Hook and display user]

If you have a track my wish is to say if the user table is not empty (which means that I have my token) change page for example